# count the number of the same and repeated words

Tags: c

My code counts the number of keywords on the given string, but I need to count the repeated keywords as 1 and count it as unique keywords.Can somebody please help me I can't figure out how I would do it :(.please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[] = "\nauto else else do while >> \nfor 1+2 == goto";
  char *keywords[] =
  { "auto", "break", "else", "case", "if" };
  int s = 0, i, x = 1;
  char *result;
  char delims[] = "  \n";
  int keyword = 0, ukeyword = 0;

  printf("Input: %s", string);
  //Count the number of lines
  for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
  {
    if (string[i] == '\n')
      ++s;
  }
  printf("\n\nNo. of lines: %d", s);

  result = strtok(string, delims);
  while (result != NULL )
  {
    for (x = 0; x != 5; x++)
    {
      if (strcmp(result, keywords[x]) == 0)
      {
        keyword++;
      }
    }

    result = strtok(NULL, delims);
  }

  printf("\nNo. of keywords: %d.\n", keyword);
  printf("\nNo. of unique keywords: %d.\n", ukeyword);
  return 0;
}
```

So the output should be:

```
Input:
auto else else do while >>
for 1+2 == goto

No. of lines:2
No. of keywords:3
No. of unique keywords:2
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: You need a set/counter data structure, which you'll have to implement.

Comment: Sir I tried saving the keywords(result) to array using strcpy but it won't work, my idea is to save all the matched keywords to an array so that I can keep track of the words that were already found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must count the occurences of each keyword separately:

```
int keyword_count[5];
```

and when you find a keyword you must increment the corrispondent counter:

```
keywords ++;
keyword_count[x] ++;
```

At the end the unique keywords are the ones which have keyword_count[x]==1

Comment: Ok Sir I will try to implement this :)

Comment: Ok Sir I am not yet allowed to Vote Up but your solution did worked! :) I am very glad.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int totalKeywords, uniqueKeywords;

struct keywordStruct
{
    char *keyword;
    int count = 0;
} keywords[5];

void updateKeywordCount(char word[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < sizeof(keywords)/sizeof(keywordStruct); i++) {
        if (strcmp(keywords[i].keyword, word) == 0) {
            if (keywords[i].count == 0) {
                uniqueKeywords += 1;
                keywords[i].count = 1;
            }
            totalKeywords += 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char word[100], currentChar;
    int i, lines = 0, charInWordCount = 0;
    keywords[0].keyword = "auto";
    keywords[1].keyword = "break";
    keywords[2].keyword = "else";
    keywords[3].keyword = "cause";
    keywords[4].keyword = "if";
    freopen("Input.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (scanf("%c", &currentChar) == 1) {
        if (currentChar == '\n' || currentChar == '\r') {
            lines += 1;
            word[charInWordCount++] = '\0';
            charInWordCount = 0;
            updateKeywordCount(word);
        } else if (currentChar == ' ') {
            word[charInWordCount++] = '\0';
            charInWordCount = 0;
            updateKeywordCount(word);
        } else {
            word[charInWordCount++] = currentChar;
        }
    }
    if (charInWordCount) {
        lines += 1;
        word[charInWordCount++] = '\0';
        updateKeywordCount(word);
    }
    printf ("No. of lines: %d\n", lines);
    printf ("No. of keywords: %d\n", totalKeywords);
    printf ("No. of unique keywords: %d\n", uniqueKeywords);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
No. of lines: 2
No. of keywords: 3
No. of unique keywords: 2
```